# NASM::Can't convert string to int with value greater than 255

Tags: linux, nasm, i386

I have an issue with converting a string to an integer (a number). Correct conversion is done only if string have value below or equal to 255 (like: port db "255",0x0).
In case integer value greater than 255 (like: port db "256",0x0), result is overflowed.
Here is example code:

```
section .bss
    PORT resw 1

section .data
    port db "256",0x0

section .text
    global _start
_start:
    pusha
    ;reset eax,ebx,edx to 0
    xor eax, eax
    xor ebx, ebx
    xor edx, edx
    .loop:
        ;compare *port+edx against 0x0; pointer arithmetic?
        cmp BYTE [port + edx], 0x0
        je .exit
        ;copy port[edx] to bl
        mov bl, BYTE [port + edx]
        ;substract '0' (48) to get 'real' integer
        sub bl, '0'
        ;each cycle multiply by 10
        imul eax, 10
        ;add ebx (not bl as eax is 32bit) to eax
        add eax, ebx
        inc edx
        jmp .loop
    .exit:
        ;convert port value to big-endian value
        shl eax, 8 
        mov [PORT], eax
    popa
    mov eax, 1
    int 0x80
```

As I mentioned above, the value stored in [PORT] is truncated. 
Now value in [PORT] is 0... Without applying shift instruction (shl eax, 8), value will be 1.

I might miss something stupid or I lack knowledge.
Please can someone explain what is wrong with this code?

Thanks

Comment: An integer and a decimal are two different things.  Please be careful.  I'm rusty, but it seems you are using a `BYTE` type, which has a maximum value of 255 (0xff), which is the 256th value (0..255).  To create an integer, you have to string together several bytes in contiguous memory space.

Comment: Paul, I using BYTE to notify compiler about size I want to compare/mov. Looks like the real problem is here 'add eax, ebx'. As eax "can't" hold value more than number 256 :(.
I changed the 'decimal' to 'a number' as it describe more closely what I want.

Comment: no, you're wrong there... `al` addresses the low 8 bits (1 byte, or 255), `ax` can hold the lowest 16 bits (2 bytes), `eax` holds lowest 32 bits or 4 bytes and `rax` (on x86_64) holds 64 bits or 8 bytes.  Check for uses of `bl` instead of `bx` or `ebx`.

Comment: I ran your program, and with a few minor corrections (add `:` to `.exit` label, add graceful exit), it works the way you describe it should, except for the `shl` part, which I'm not sure what you're trying to do.. I don't think that makes it big endian.

Comment: Paul, thanks for help. Thanks for pointing out typos, I will correct it in original post.
The part of 'shl' help me to convert a number to big-endian value.
Here is the flow: a. 80 << 8 = 20480 b. hex(20480) = 0x5000 c. 0x0050 = 80. I still wasn't able to convert string with value "256" to a number 256... Getting 0 (zero).

Comment: FIXED! I was checking the exit error code in bash shell (echo $?). Which is only one byte length (2**8 = 256). This is the reason I get zero after increasing value greater or equal 256. The problem is solved.